# How to detect triggered date of an actionable Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift2

I have a reminder in my app. In which I've created daily repetition of a notification. Now multiple notifications can be seen in my notification center. And since it's actionable notification user can tap "Yes" or "No".

I've listener for it as follow:

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI


class NotificationSetup: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{

    let requestIdentifier = "SampleRequest"
    let salahTimeArr =
        [

            [ "salahName": "Fajar", "time" : DateComponents.init( hour: 7, minute: 0 )],
            [ "salahName": "Zuhar", "time" : DateComponents.init( hour: 14, minute: 0 )],
            [ "salahName": "Asar", "time" : DateComponents.init( hour: 18, minute: 0 )],
            [ "salahName": "Maghrib", "time" : DateComponents.init( hour: 19, minute: 30 )],
            [ "salahName": "Isha", "time" : DateComponents.init( hour: 22, minute: 0 ) ]

    ]

    //============================================================

    func createNotificationCategory()
    {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
        {
            (granted, error) in

            let actionYes = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "yes", title: "Yes", options: [])

            let actionNo = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "no", title: "No", options: [])

            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "SalahOfferedActionableNotification", actions: [actionYes, actionNo], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

        }

    }


    //----------------------------------

    func setNotifications()
    {

        self.createNotificationCategory()


        if ( UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isNotificationSet") == false )
        {

            for salahDict in salahTimeArr
            {

                print(salahDict["salahName"])

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Did you offer"
                content.subtitle = salahDict["salahName"] as! String
                content.body = "Its Fard!"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
                content.categoryIdentifier = "SalahOfferedActionableNotification"

                //------------------------

                let date = salahDict["time"] as! DateComponents

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)


                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

                //------------------------

                let notificationSingletonObj = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                notificationSingletonObj.delegate = self

                //------------------------

                notificationSingletonObj.add(request)
                {
                    (error) in

                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set( true, forKey: "isNotificationSet" )
        }
    }

    //============================================================

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        let salahName = response.notification.request.content.subtitle
        let date = response.notification.date

        if response.actionIdentifier == "yes"
        {
            print("User tapped 'Yes' button on notification for Salah: \(salahName)")

            UserDefaults.standard.set( true, forKey: salahName )

            Calculation().addSalah(forSalah : salahName, offered: 1 )

            userDefaults.set( Date(), forKey: "dataCapturedForDate")
        }

    }


}
```

I want to read date of notification (Triggered Date). I found following

```
let date = response.notification.date
```

But as apple documentation says it supports iOS 10 & later. But I want support till iOS7.

[image]

Please refer notification centre image to understand it clearly.
I've same title, description & all notification info similar. And I want to detect which notification user tapped. Weather it was Monday's notification or Tuesday's notification. Weather it is "A" or "B"

[image]

Comment: You want it to work in iOS 7 but you're using `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` which is only available in iOS 10.

Comment: So please help me. Am new to iOS. What should I use.

Comment: Either user `UILocalNotification` or change your targeted audience. 79% are on ios10 https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Answer (score 0):

There is `fireDate` property of `UILocalNotification`. You can use it. Also to support iOS7 you need to use `UILocalNotification` instead of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

To fire a local notification

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
let fireDate = Date()
localNotification.fireDate = fireDate
localNotification.alertBody = "Your alert message"
localNotification.repeatInterval = .day
UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

In your app delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
  notification.fireDate
}
```

Comment: I can't set ID bcz I want to read date when user taps. But I can't even set date bcz it is daily notification.

Comment: You want to read the date of the notification fired or when user taps on your notification? You can get the current time when your method gets called which is the time when user taps

Comment: No it's incorret bcz user can tap on notification after few days. But the date when user interacted with it, it is not actual fired dated of that notification. It was there since last few days. Then What????

Comment: You want fired date of the notification, then just put that date in notification while firing it.

Comment: @RAISIQBAL you just need to use `UILocalNotification` and implement the delegate method `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)` and access the `fireDate` property of the local notificaiton

Comment: @indere UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS 10. Use UNNotificationRequest instead.

Comment: Yes it's deprecated but not removed. So it still will work for how long that I don't know. So it's your decision to go with deprecated api and support ios7 devices or go with latest and support only ios 10 devices. I would have chosen ios10 since adoption rate of ios is much higher